# Continuous Promise/A+ loading

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

So I'd like to have these continuous, asynchronous, data loading in browser. I like Promises, they're good, aren't they? Fun to program, easy to read.

In my problem, I won't to continuously update some resource in the browser, for example an image. There are two parts then: producer and consumer. In synchronous code it could look like this:

```
var p = producer(),
    data = null;

while (data = p.next()) {
    consumer.update(data)
}
```

How would this translate to asynchronous, Promise/A+ enabled code?

**UPDATE**

I ended up using the following base class:

```
class Stream
    input  : null
    output : null
    # @param  {function} callback
    end    : (callback) -> @end_callback = callback
    # @param  {Stream} writable
    # @return {Stream}
    pipe   : (writable) -> writable.input = @ ; @output = writable
    # @param  {function} callback
    # @return {Stream}
    data   : (callback) ->
        setTimeout =>
            last = @
            chain = [@]
            while last.input != null
                last = last.input
                chain.push(last)
            last = chain.pop()
            next = =>
                thenable = last.read()
                if thenable is null and @end_callback
                    return @end_callback()
                thenable.then (value) =>
                    if not chain.length
                        callback(value)
                        @data(callback)
                    else
                        last = chain.pop()
                        last.write(value)
                        next()
            next()
        , 0
        @
```

Just implement `read` method, returning a `Promise` or null, or both `read` and `write` to create transforming stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're talking of is more a Stream than Promises - maybe there's a better fitting library. If not, you might want to have a look at my ["Lazy Promise Stream" implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17414193/1048572).

> How would this [polling] translate to asynchronous, Promise/A+ enabled code?

The `producer()`'s `next()` method would return promises. Then, you'd loop over them in a recursive manner:

```
function getNext() {
    return p.next().then(function(data) {
         consumer.update(data);
         return getNext();
    });
}
getNext();
```

<sub>The `return`s could be omitted if you knew it was an infinite stream without errors, as `getNext()` would be always pending</sub>

Comment: Nice, this is what I came up with too, I was just wondering what else is out there. Indeed my case is stream like. Thx for the link.

Answer (score -1):

I think from your description you'd probably want to use 'Web Workers' if you have a producer consumer pair.

The 'Worker' would be sent work and then return messages at certain points, such as when it's complete. 
You can listen to the `onmessage` event in the consumer and decide what to do, such as send more work, or process the result if it's complete.

Have a look at the MDN guide and see if it fits your need:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with WebWorker, my use-case is different, the producer actually uses XHR so it can't be executed in WebWorker.

Comment: XHR can be used in web workers, as detailed in the link I posted and further expanded on in here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_workers_in_extensions